# How to use delegates in general (but also within Soundcloud).

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, delegates

I am a noob when it comes to delegates, but I'm sure this will be a piece of cake for more experienced coders such as yourselves.

I have my app delegate setup up like this:

```
@interface iPhoneTestAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, SCSoundCloudAPIAuthenticationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    iPhoneTestAppViewController *viewController;
    SCSoundCloudAPI *soundCloudAPIMaster;
}


- (SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPIMaster;
{
    if (!soundCloudAPIMaster) {
        SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration *scAPIConfig = [SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration configurationForProductionWithConsumerKey:kTestAppConsumerKey
                                                                                                    consumerSecret:kTestAppConsumerSecret
                                                                                                                callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCallbackURL]];
        soundCloudAPIMaster = [[SCSoundCloudAPI alloc] initWithDelegate:nil authenticationDelegate:self apiConfiguration:scAPIConfig];
        // make shure to register the myapp url scheme to your app :) 
    }
    return soundCloudAPIMaster;
}
```

which contains a method that gets called back:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Then I have my viewController set up with this in the .h file:

```
@interface iPhoneTestAppViewController : UIViewController <SCSoundCloudAPIDelegate>
```

and then in viewController.m I have a method that pushes a webview. Basically what I'm trying to do is get the callback method from the delegate file to callback to a method in the viewController.m file. (I would like to close my webView when I receive the callback).

Any ideas? Have I presented enough information to decipher my problem? Is this solvable as a general delegate issue or is it more of an Soundcloud specific problem?

**EDIT 1**

Here was an attempt to fix my problem that didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate of the SoundClound variable to `self` otherwise the variable cannot pickup who the delegate is.

```
initWithDelegate:self ....
```

Comment: Okay, this seems very helpful. But then what do I do? Just copy my 'application handleOpenURL method' to the viewController file?

Answer (score 0):

just write this code in ViewDidload Event...

yourcontrolname.delegate = self;

Comment: I got this there already:  scAPI = [appDelegate.soundCloudAPIMaster copyWithAPIDelegate:self];
Would that cause a problem?

Comment: just write like below in your viewdidload scAPI.delegate =self;

Comment: It doesn't like it. I get Expected unqualified-id :( To be clear by yourcontrolname you mean my viewController, correct?